# Dois formulários em uma página

Tags: php, codeigniter, mvc, formulário

Bom galera eu tenho uma view com dois formulário e ambos possuem `action="current_url()"`, ou seja, os dois executarão a ação na mesma página, o problema é que independente do botão que eu clique para enviar o formulário ele sempre executa os dois gerando as mesmas mensagens de erro, como se ele reconhece apenas um form, queria saber se tem alguma forma de utilizar dois formulários distintos e executá-los na mesma página/método

```
<?php 
if (validation_errors() != '') {
        $mostra_box_msg = 'show';
    }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#box-msg").<?php echo $mostra_box_msg ?>();
        $("#abre_resposta").click(function(){
            $("#box-msg").toggle("slow")
       });
   });
</script>

<h3>Pergunta:</h3>
<?php 
    echo "<p>".anchor("area_tecnico", "<i class='icon-circle-arrow-left'></i> Voltar", array("class"=>"btn btn-small"))."</p>"; 
    if ($this->session->flashdata('msgok') != "")   echo '<p class="text-success">'.$this->session->flashdata('msgok').'</p>';
?>

<blockquote>
  <p>Dados Gerais</p>
</blockquote>
<?php 
    $seguimento     =   $this->uri->segment(3);
    $dados  =   $this->db->query("SELECT 
i_chamada
, titulo
, DATE_FORMAT(dt_abertura, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') AS data_abertura
, DATE_FORMAT(dt_prevista, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') AS data_prevista
, DATE_FORMAT(dt_encerramento, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') AS data_encerramento
, status
, (SELECT nome FROM tecnicos AS z WHERE z.i_tecnico=a.i_tecnico) AS nome_tecnico
, (SELECT nome FROM areas AS z WHERE z.i_area=a.i_area) AS nome_area
FROM chamados AS a
WHERE i_chamada = $seguimento")->result_array();

    if ($dados[0]['status'] == 'N') {
        $status = 'Novo';
        $type   = 'info';
    } elseif ($dados[0]['status'] == 'E') {
        $status = 'Em Andamento';
        $type   = '';
    } elseif ($dados[0]['status'] == 'R') {
        $status = 'Resolvido';
        $type   = 'success';
    } elseif ($dados[0]['status'] == 'C') {
        $status = 'Cancelado';
        $type   = 'error';
    } else {
        $status = 'Aguardando Usuário';
        $type   = 'warning';
    }
?>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="25%" class="text-center">Número de Identificação</th>
        <th width="25%" class="text-center">Técnico</th>
        <th width="25%" class="text-center">Status</th>
        <th width="25%" class="text-center">Área</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $dados[0]['i_chamada'] ?></td>
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo ($dados[0]['nome_tecnico'] == NULL ? '<span class="muted">Aguardando Resposta</span>' : $dados[0]['nome_tecnico']) ?></td>
        <td class="text-center"><span class="label label-<?php echo ($type == 'error') ? 'important' :  $type ?>"><?php echo $status ?></span></td>
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $dados[0]['nome_area'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="25%" class="text-center">Assunto</th>
        <th width="25%" class="text-center">Data Abertura</th>
        <th width="25%" class="text-center">Data Prevista</th>
        <th width="25%" class="text-center">Data Encerramento</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $dados[0]['titulo'] ?></td>
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $dados[0]['data_abertura'] ?></td>
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo ($dados[0]['data_prevista'] == NULL) ? '<a href="#ModalData" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>' : $dados[0]['data_prevista'] ?> </td>
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo ($dados[0]['data_encerramento'] == NULL) ? '<a href="#ModalData" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>' : $dados[0]['data_encerramento'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<br>
<br>
<blockquote>
  <p>Mensagens</p>
</blockquote>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="15%" class="text-center">Enviado Por</th>
        <th width="50%" class="text-center">Mensagem</th>
        <th width="10%" class="text-center">Data e Hora</th>
        <th width="5%" class="text-center">Código</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

<?php 

    $interacoes = $this->db->query("SELECT
i_interacao
, DATE_FORMAT(dt_interacao, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') AS data_interacao
, descricao
, i_tecnico
, status
, (SELECT nome FROM tecnicos AS z WHERE z.i_tecnico=a.i_tecnico) AS nome_tecnico
, (SELECT nome FROM clientes AS z WHERE z.i_cliente=a.i_cliente) AS nome_cliente
FROM interacoes AS a
WHERE i_chamada = $seguimento")->result_array();

    foreach ($interacoes as $key) :

    if ($key['status'] == 'N') {
        //$status = 'Novo';
        $type   = 'info';
    } elseif ($key['status'] == 'E') {
        //$status = 'Em Andamento';
        $type   = '';
    } elseif ($key['status'] == 'R') {
        //$status = 'Resolvido';
        $type   = 'success';
    } elseif ($key['status'] == 'C') {
        //$status = 'Cancelado';
        $type   = 'error';
    } else {
        //$status = 'Aguardando Usuário';
        $type   = 'warning';
    }

    if ($key['i_tecnico'] == NULL) {
        echo '
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">'.$key['nome_cliente'].'</td>
                <td class="text-center">'.$key['descricao'].'</td>
                <td class="text-center">'.$key['data_interacao'].'</td>
                <td class="text-center">#'.$key['i_interacao'].'</td>
            </tr>
        ';
    } else {
        echo '
            <tr class="'.$type.'">
                <td class="text-center"><b>'.$key['nome_tecnico'].'</b></td>
                <td class="text-center">'.$key['descricao'].'</td>
                <td class="text-center">'.$key['data_interacao'].'</td>
                <td class="text-center">#'.$key['i_interacao'].'</td>
            </tr>
        ';
    }

    endforeach;


?>

    </tbody>
</table>

<div style="clear: both; margin-bottom: 5px"></div>
<a id="abre_resposta" class="pull-right btn btn-mini btn btn-info"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Nova Resposta</a>
<br>
<br>
<div style="width:62%; margin:0 auto" id="box-msg">
<?php echo form_open(current_url(), 'class="form-horizontal"'); ?>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <?php 
            echo form_error('descricao', '<p class="text-error">', '</p>');
        ?>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Status</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select name="status">
            <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Selecione um Status</option>
            <option value="N">Novo</option>
            <option value="E">Em Andamento</option>
            <option value="R">Resolvido</option>
            <option value="C">Cancelado</option>
            <option value="P">Pendente</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Mensagem</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <?php echo form_textarea(array('name'=>'descricao', 'value'=>set_value('descricao'), 'class'=>'input-xxlarge', 'rows'=>'2')); ?>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Observação</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <?php echo form_textarea(array('name'=>'tecnico', 'value'=>set_value('tecnico'), 'class'=>'input-xxlarge', 'rows'=>'2')); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar Resposta</button>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->

<?php 
    $hidden = array(
        'seguimento_hidden' => $this->uri->segment(3)
    );
?>

<div id="ModalData" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Alteração de Datas</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
      <?php 
        echo form_open(current_url(), 'class="form-horizontal"', $hidden);
      ?>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Data e Hora Prevista</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'dt_prevista', 'value'=>set_value('dt_prevista'), 'class'=>'date-time-mask')); ?>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Data e Hora Encerrada</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'dt_encerramento', 'value'=>set_value('dt_encerramento'), 'class'=>'date-time-mask')); ?>
            </div>
          </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Salvar Dados</button>
  </div>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#ModalData').modal('show')
    });
</script>
```

O segundo form está dentro de uma modal do bootstrap onde irei utilizado apenas para atualizar duas datas do banco

Comment: Mete aí o código da view para entender melhor o problema!

Comment: já atualizei e meti o código ali

Comment: Seu código está muito desorganizado e fora da abordagem MVC do Codeigniter. Quais erros aparecem?

Comment: não existe erro algum, a pergunta é como eu utilizo dois formulário distintos em um único método do controlador

Comment: @JhonatanOliveira na verdade o código parece estar certo, mas ele colocou tudo junto para podermos ver numa mesma página... pelo menos parece ser isso rsrs

Comment: sim, na real o modal está fora da página mais ambos os formulários utilizam o mesmo controlador e o mesmo método para validar os campos e executar as ações

Comment: Não estava clara essa mesclagem para mim, por isso o comentário de que estava fora da abordagem. Seria interessante cada form ter um "name", talvez por isso esteja executando ambos os forms. Ah, e o segundo button falta o "submit" no seu código @Japa

Comment: Ok obrigado, mais como utilizo o name no form e recupero eles no controlador para poder usar um form_validation para cada formulário?

Comment: * Verificando se o form enviado não está vazio `$this->input->post('form');` Ou os campos individualmente; Esse exemplo é legal: http://bavotasan.com/2009/processing-multiple-forms-on-one-page-with-php/

Comment: Acho que esse exemplo vai servir exatamente pro que eu preciso!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consegui resolver da seguinte forma, criei um campo hidden em cada form com o mesmo name e value diferentes para a identificação no controller

```
<input type="hidden" name="acao_form" value="cad-resposta" style="display:none;" />
<input type="hidden" name="acao_form" value="cad-datas" style="display:none;" />
```

e no controlador validei qual valor era retornado no submit

```
  $acao_form = $this->input->post('acao_form');

  if ($acao_form == 'cad-resposta') {
     //cadastra uma coisa       
  }

  if ($acao_form == 'cad-datas') {
     //cadastra outra           
  }
```